# Stamp of approval on something

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Suppose you are going to formally convey that somebody's words is confirming your words; in my mother language, when it comes to such need and one tends to talk a bit formally, there is a fixed term; "stamp of approval" is it's precise translation; how one can say such thing in AE; please have a consideration on my self-made example:

> - His verbal consent was as good as a stamp of approval on the job I did.
> - His verbal consent was as good as a stamp of approval on what I said.

Do you Americans say such thing in daily formal situations?

Comment: A-friend, we expect you do do a little research before asking a question. Did you try googling **stamp of approval**. I did. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seal-or-stamp-of-approval

Comment: @JavaLatte thank you very much for trying to show me the correct way to bring up my questions; but I have to point to this matter that most of my questions are based on AE; it is sometimes hard to differentiate between these two through searching in Google; at least I guess sometimes my literacy doesn't suffice for that at the time being. :)

Comment: Meanwhile sometimes researching through internet for a specific sentence in my mind would require lots of time without any guarantee to obtain needed information; this is another reason why I bring up such questions which sound I did not have requisite research prior to setting forth.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Stamp of approval* is really an "either/or" concept, either something has a stamp of approval or it doesn't.  There is no "in-between."  So using it comparatively, e.g. "this is as good as a stamp of a approval" sounds weird.

Also, since *stamp of approval* is a well-known saying, it almost never refers to an actual physical stamp, but the way you are saying it sounds like there's a real stamp involved.

You can say:

> His verbal consent was the stamp of approval on my job / on what I said.